# How to detect if the user turned on or off WiFi debug

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver

I need to detect if the user has wifi debugging mode turned on or off when it opens the app or as soon as he changes it.

I already have a Broadcast receiver for the USB debugging, but can't find a away to detect the wi-fi one.

Thanks

Comment: This might help https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-aware

Answer (score 0):

```
private void detectWifiDebug() {
mSettingsObserver = new ContentObserver(mHandler) {
  @Override
  public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri) {
    /* do stuff, for some reason when it turns on this is called twice */
  }
};
getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(
    Settings.Global.getUriFor("adb_wifi_enabled"), false,
    mSettingsObserver);
}
```

I found this code that seems to work.